# How can I use react-share with SpeedDial of Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-share

I'm trying to make a SpeedDial of social share buttons with React, [react-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share) and [SpeedDial from Material UI](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/speed-dial/), but react-share requires that I use its buttons.

I have the following SpeedDial code:

```
const actions = [
    {icon: <FacebookIcon size={32} round />, name: 'Facebook'},
    {icon: <TwitterIcon size={32} round />, name: 'Twitter'},
    {icon: <WhatsappIcon size={32} round />, name: 'WhatsApp'},
    {icon: <TelegramIcon size={32} round />, name: 'Telegram'},
    {icon: <EmailIcon size={32} round />, name: 'E-mail'}
];


<SpeedDial
      ariaLabel="SpeedDial example"
      className={classes.shareButton}
      icon={<SpeedDialIcon icon={<ShareIcon/>} openIcon={<CloseIcon/>}/>}
      onClose={handleClose}
      onOpen={handleOpen}
      open={open}
      direction='up'
    >
      {actions.map((action) => (
        <SpeedDialAction
          key={action.name}
          icon={action.icon}
          tooltipTitle={action.name}
          onClick={action.onClick}
        />
      ))}
    </SpeedDial>
```

I don't know how can I trigger a share action from `action.onClick`. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, I'm using onClick on SpeedDialACtion and its working for me in other scenario

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can pass the `FacebookShareButton`, for example, as icon os the `SpeedDialAction`.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?